# grep some word whose starting 10 characters are known from 20 characters last 10 characters are dynamic

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find, sh

I am running a abcd.sh file which internally calling a python file , the python script is giving some output which I am taking in some variable and trying to grep some word whose starting 10 characters are known from 20 characters last 10 characters are dynamic , and that word is multiple time.

I want to grep the word.
ex: in below log sample I want to search `"Request-Id-12977-1233"` where `"Request-Id"` is fixed

```
1::com.demo.log.Demo::main::Sat Dec 15 01:42:43 EST 2012:: requestID: Request-Id-12977-1233  Demo::main
1::com.demo.log.Demo::main::Sat Dec 2012::  requestID: Request-Id-12977-1233  Demo::main
1::com.demo.log.Demo::main:: 2012:: requestID: Request-Id-12977-1233  Demo::main
1::com.demo.log.Demo::main:  requestID: Request-Id-12977-1233  Demo::main
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash - how to check the string length using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367882/bash-how-to-check-the-string-length-using-grep)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer finally, I tried this previously but not worked that, may be some mistake was there.
--taking response of python script

```
initiateResponse=$(python pythonscript.py argument1 "argument2" "arguments3")
```

-- echo output and then pipe grep and then pipe tail to take last value as there are multiple

```
requestId=$(echo initiateReposnse | grep -o "Request-Id-\w*" | tail -n 1)
echo "request Id $ requestId"
```

Comment: That's not valid shell script syntax. You can't have whitespace around the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: @tripleee Ye while typing here I added space for better visibility,

Comment: Wrecking the syntax for legibility is not a good idea. You should probably not use `\w` in regular `grep` (this is a Perl extension which generally is not supported, though some implementations have picked up some Perl goodies as unofficial extensions).

Comment: @triplee Can you suggest if not\w then what should I use.

Comment: `\w` corresponds to POSIX `[[:alnum:]_]`; matter of taste whether you really want the underscore there.